# INSERT SELECT with differed table/col stucture

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert-select

I am trying to create a INSERT SELECT statement which inserts and converts data from `Imported_table` to `Destination_table`.

**Imported_table**

```
+------------------+-----------------------+
| Id (varchar(10)) | genre (varchar(4000)) |
+------------------+-----------------------+
| 6                | Comedy                |
+------------------+-----------------------+
| 5                | Comedy                |
+------------------+-----------------------+
| 1                | Action                |
+------------------+-----------------------+
```

**Destination_table** (How it should be looking)

```
+-----------------------------+----------------------------+
| genre_name (PK,varchar(50)) | description (varchar(255)) |
+-----------------------------+----------------------------+
| Comedy                      | Description of Comedy      |
+-----------------------------+----------------------------+
| Action                      | Description of Action      |
+-----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

- `Imported_table.Id` isn't used at all but is still in this (old) table
- `Destination_table.genre_name` is a primairy key and should be unique `(distinct)`
- `Destination_table.description` is compiled with `CONCAT('Description of ',genre)`

**My best try**

```
INSERT INTO testdb.dbo.Destination_table (genre_name, description)
SELECT DISTINCT Genre,
       LEFT(Genre,50) AS genre_name,
       CAST(CONCAT('Description of ',Genre) AS varchar(255)) AS description
FROM   MYIMDB.dbo.Imported_table
```

Gives the error: `The select list for the INSERT statement contains more items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are `selecting` 3 `columns` and `inserting` 2, either `select` 3 `insert` 3 or `select` 2 and `insert` 2.

Comment: you have 3 fields in the select to insert into two fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The largest error in your query is that you are trying to insert 3 columns into a destination table having only two columns.  That being said, I would just use `LEFT` for both inserted values and take as much space as the new table can hold:

```
INSERT INTO testdb.dbo.Destination_table (genre_name, description)
SELECT DISTINCT
    LEFT(Genre, 50),
    'Description of ' + LEFT(Genre, 240)    -- 240 + 15 = 255
FROM MYIMDB.dbo.Imported_table;
```

As a side note, the original `genre` field is 4000 characters wide, and your new table structure runs the risk of throwing away a lot of information.  It is not clear whether you are concerned with this, but it is worth pointing out.

Comment: Thanks alot! I see what I've done wrong. I tought DISTINCT handled data a differend way..

Comment: @ThomasBeumer Out of curiosity, did you think that `DISTINCT` would choose between `Genre` and `LEFT(Genre, 50)` ?

Comment: I tought that `DISTINCT genre` would only select 1 of each `genre` but without inserting

Answer (score 1):

This means your `SELECT` (genre, genre_name,description) and `INSERT` (genre_name, description) lists don't match.  You need to `SELECT`  the same number of fields as you are specifying in your `INSERT`.

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO testdb.dbo.Destination_table (genre_name, description)
SELECT DISTINCT Genre,
       CAST(CONCAT('Description of ',Genre) AS varchar(255)) AS description
FROM   MYIMDB.dbo.Imported_table
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 columns in your SELECT, try:

```
INSERT INTO testdb.dbo.Destination_table (genre_name, description)
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(Genre,50) AS genre_name,
       CAST(CONCAT('Description of ',Genre) AS varchar(255)) AS description
FROM   MYIMDB.dbo.Imported_table
```